# How to export SSRS report to PDF using URL Access from PowerBI Report Server?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, power-bi-report-server

**Assume I have a PowerBI report server at the following version:** PowerBI Report Server Version: 1.5.7074.36177 (May 2019)

**Assume I have a report at a URL like the following that will run in a browser with no params:** `https://<HOST>/<VIR_DIR>/report/<MY_REPORTS>/Report%20On%20Stuff`

I'd like to use [URL Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access?view=sql-server-ver15) as a means to export a report to PDF rather than opening in a browser.

**The following URL results in a redirect to the top-level reports folder with no PDF exported:** `https://<HOST>/<VIR_DIR>?/report/<MY_REPORTS>/Report%20On%20Stuff&rs:Format=PDF`

**I also tried this variation of the URL, which also results in a redirect to the top-level reports folder with no PDF exported:** `https://<HOST>/<VIR_DIR>/report?/<MY_REPORTS>/Report%20On%20Stuff&rs:Format=PDF`

**And this variation of the URL, which redirects to what appears to be a directory listing of reports in the <MY_REPORTS> folder (again with no PDF):** `https://<HOST>/<VIR_DIR>/report/<MY_REPORTS>?/Report%20On%20Stuff&rs:Format=PDF`

Comment: Either you have over-obfuscated your URL or you have syntax errors within it.  Can you please add your URL with more descriptive blanking of sensitive data, making sure to include all special characters in exactly the right place

Comment: @iamdave, I realized I was missing the '?' in the URL, but I still can't get this to work. (Question updated)

Comment: Have you tried this version of the URL, as none of your examples are in this format: `https://servername/ReportServer_THESQLINSTANCE/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2freportfolder%2freport+name+with+spaces&rs:Format=PDF`

Comment: @iamdave, This worked: ```https://<HOST>/<REPORT_SERVER_NAME>/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2F<MY_REPORTS>%2FReport%20On%20Stuff&rs:Format=PDF```. If you write up an answer, I'll accept it. Or I can write the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try the alternative URL syntax that is available, as none of your examples are in this format and it is the one I have always used with SSRS exports:

```
https://servername/ReportServer_THESQLINSTANCE/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2freportfolder%2freport+name+with+spaces&rs:Format=PDF
```

Comment: What should I replace THESQLINSTANCE with? I do this and it just takes me to the reporting home page with no error message. Also don't you need an HTTPS certificate to use https in the URL like that? My report server doesn't have an HTTPS certificate.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald You should replace `ReportServer_THESQLINSTANCE` in the above with the name of your Report Server.  That you are getting to the Reporting home page shows you that your link is working, just that you are perhaps not providing the right URL parameters to get to the report you are after.

Comment: thanks, turns out my admins removed the symbolic link to the server and I had to use the actual server name to connect :/